# can't load .dll file into python script

Tags: python, c, dll

I would like to call C function from python script on windows.For that I include .dll of the C code in python.But it doesnt call that function and while running python didnt show any error.

C code: sum.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int our_function(int num_numbers, int numbers)
{
  return num_numbers*numbers;
}
```

Python:sum.py

```
import ctypes
sum = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('C:\Python27\sum.dll')
our_function = sum.our_function
our_function.restype = ctypes.c_int
our_function.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int]
result = our_function(10,5)
print result
```

DLL file is made by Cygwin compiler.

can anyone tell me what is wrong in this?

Comment: Why are you still using an ancient Python version? Where exactly is the error? What is the error message? That said, you should escape strings that are supposed to contain backslashes. Also, check out what symbols the DLL exports and whether its depencies are met using dependencywalker.

Comment: Please read up on `calling conventions` in https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html there are several in Windows world, and cygwin might just use something other than what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some typos in the question.

```
return num_numbers*number; // should be numbers (number is not declared)
```

Python code typo:

```
sum = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('C:\Python27\sum.dll')
# should be r'C:\Python27\sum.dll' or 'C:\\Python27\\sum.dll'
```

And use explicit **_cdecl** convention:

```
int _cdecl our_function(int num_numbers, int numbers)
```

Comment: P.S. In C++ files use this declaration:  `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int our_function(int num_numbers, int numbers)`. C++ compiler makes implicit prefixes and suffixes for function name in binary file if explicit `extern "C"` is not specified.

Comment: This is C code only.The python compiler doesn't identify that dll file and it cannot continue the execution of python code.

Comment: I did the same as what you suggest,but still the same problem.can you help me ?

Comment: Did you try explicit **_cdecl** convention?

Comment: No.can you tell me how to use this convention for calling C function form python?..is it possible?

Comment: except DLL is there any other way to call C function from python script?

Comment: int _cdecl our_function(int num_numbers, int numbers)